Are build-deps packages required to stay installed or can we purge them?
I'm often following SimpleBackportCreation to create custom backports for various packages that don't exist in stable branch.
One of the steps is to install build-deps with sudo mk-build-deps --install --remove command.
The question is, once the backport is installed, do I need to keep build-deps packages installed, or is it safe to purge them once custom backport is installed?
I primarily want to save on some space but secondary reason is that updating a backport might uninstall/upgrade previous build-deps from previous version but the build for the new backport version might fail, so I'm wondering if in that case, now removed build-deps packages will affect old backport initially made and already installed.

Bottom line, can I purge *-build-deps?

Yes, it is safe to purge any build-deps packages after the build is done.
They are things that a particular package needs during the build phase only.
From the viewpoint of checking the validity of package dependency information, having only the declared build-deps available during the build process is a good thing: it ensures any undeclared build-deps cause the build to fail, and so the dependency information will get corrected. I understand this is exactly how Debian's autobuilder systems work.
However, do keep in mind that if you ever need to rebuild the package (perhaps because a bug or a security vulnerability is later discovered in the source code version you built), you will need to reinstall the build-deps again in the system you use for building your custom *.debs.
If your build system is running low on disk space, and your build process is not fully automated, get yourself some more disk space so you don't have to play "disk space Tetris"! It is simply not worth your time.

It’s also safe to autoremove or autopurge after purging the build-deps packages, to remove any unnecessary transitive build dependencies.
